# What is the different between /n and /i parameters of RegSvr32.exe?

Tags: windows, winapi, com

To register a COM server, we run something like in elevated mode:

```
regsvr32.exe com.dll
```

To perform per-user registration, execute in user account:

```
regsvr32.exe /n /i:user com.dll
```

regsvr32.exe support these parameters:

```
/u - Unregister server 
/i - Call DllInstall passing it an optional [cmdline]; when used with /u calls dll uninstall 
/n - do not call DllRegisterServer; this option must be used with /i 
/s – Silent; display no message boxes (added with Windows XP and Windows Vista)
```

When create a COM server in Delphi, these methods were exported:

```
exports
  DllGetClassObject,
  DllCanUnloadNow,
  DllRegisterServer,
  DllUnregisterServer,
  DllInstall;
```

I notice these will happen:

1. "regsvr32.exe com.dll" invoke DllRegisterServer.
2. "regsvr32.exe /u com.dll" invoke DllUnregisterServer.
3. "regsvr32.exe /n /i:user com.dll" invoke DllInstall.
4. "regsvr32.exe /u /n /i:user com.dll" invoke DllInstall.

I am confuse with parameters /n and /i as well as DllUnregisterServer and DllInstall.  Is there any different?

Also, why "/u /n /i:user" invoke Dllinstall?  I notice the corresponding registry entry in "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes" was removed.

Comment: /n can *only* be used with /i so it's not "between".

Comment: Any different using "/n /i" and without paramters (DllRegisterServer)?  When to use "/n /i" and when not using any parameters?

Comment: So then "When to use DllRegisterServer instead of (just) DllInstall"?

Comment: Or in short, when to use DllRegisterServer and when to use DllInstall?  Is there any different?

Comment: Yes, there is a difference. DllRegisterServer() is most commonly used, but DllInstall() is more flexible because you can send parameters to it.

Comment: The source code for regsvr32 is available. It's one of the VS sample projects. Get it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177531(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Essentially it comes down to "do what the DLL author tells you to do". If it's framework provided functionality, then you'll need to check the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The documentation for DllInstall()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759846.aspx) explains the difference:

> DllInstall is used only for application installation and setup. It
>   should not be called by an application. It is similar in purpose to
>   DllRegisterServer or DllUnregisterServer. Unlike these functions,
>   DllInstall takes an input string which can be used to specify a
>   variety of different actions. This allows a DLL to be installed in
>   more than one way, based on any criteria that is appropriate.
>
> To use DllInstall with regsvr32, add a "/i" flag followed by a colon
>   (:) and a string. The string will be passed to DllInstall as the
>   pszCmdLine parameter. If you omit the colon and string, pszCmdLine
>   will be set to NULL. The following example would be used to install a
>   DLL.
>
> regsvr32 /i:"Install_1" dllname.dll
>
> DllInstall is invoked with
>   bInstall set to TRUE and pszCmdLine set to "Install_1". To uninstall a
>   DLL, use the following:
>
> regsvr32 /u /i:"Install_1" dllname.dll
>
> With
>   both of the above examples, DllRegisterServer or DllUnregisterServer
>   will also be called. To call DllInstall only, add a "/n" flag.
>
> regsvr32 /n /i:"Install_1" dllname.dll

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to just skip using regsvr32.exe at all -- it's about as easy to just do the job yourself:

```
int register(char const *DllName) { 
        HMODULE library = LoadLibrary(DllName); 
        if (NULL == library) { 
                // unable to load DLL 
                // use GetLastError() to find out why. 
                return -1;      // or a value based on GetLastError() 
        } 
        STDAPI (*DllRegisterServer)(void); 
        DllRegisterServer = GetProcAddress(library, "DllRegisterServer"); 
        if (NULL == DllRegisterServer) { 
                // DLL probably isn't a control -- it doesn't contain a 
                // DllRegisterServer function. At this point, you might 
                // want to look for a DllInstall function instead. This is 
                //  what RegSvr32 calls when invoked with '/i' 
                return -2; 
        } 
        int error; 
        if (NOERROR == (error=DllRegisterServer())) { 
                // It thinks it registered successfully. 
                return 0; 
        } 
        else 
                return error; 
}
```

This particular code calls `DllRegisterServer`, but it's trivial to parameterize it to call `DllInstall`, `DllUninstall`, etc., as you wish. This removes any question about what gets called when, etc.

Comment: -1 doesn't answer the question that was asked, a question that can be answered.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You're undoubtedly right -- it would have been better to answer the question he asked than to try to actually help him instead. I should probably just be kicked off permanently for doing such a horrible thing.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Your answer do help me too although not direct answer to the question.  I learn from your answer too by register the dll using programming technique instead of using command line.

Comment: Thanks, it is really helpful in my case.