# difference between regsvr32 with /i and without parameter

Tags: winapi, com, vb6, cmd, regsvr32

I am able to register a COM-DLL (written in VB6) `dowFct.dll` succesfully with

```
regsvr32 dowFct.dll
```

But when I try to do it with

```
regsvr32 dowFct.dll /i
```

I am getting the Error (translated from german to english):

The module dowfct.dll was loaded but the DllInstall entry point was not found.

I am asking me, if it is not the same to use regsvr32 with /i and without any additional parameter?
Can someone help me in this case whats going wrong? - Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the different between /n and /i parameters of RegSvr32.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990216/what-is-the-different-between-n-and-i-parameters-of-regsvr32-exe)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Without the `/i` option, regsvr32 loads the DLL and calls the exported function [`DllRegisterServer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682162.aspx).
- With the `/i` option, regsvr32 loads the DLL and calls the exported function [`DllInstall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb759846.aspx).

Clearly your DLL does not export `DllInstall` and so it would seem likely that it expects to be registered by a call to `DllRegisterServer`. So, omit the `/i` option when calling regsvr32.

The documentation for [`DllInstall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb759846.aspx) explains the difference between these two functions:

> DllInstall is used only for application installation and setup. It
>   should not be called by an application. It is similar in purpose to
>   DllRegisterServer or DllUnregisterServer. Unlike these functions,
>   DllInstall takes an input string which can be used to specify a
>   variety of different actions. This allows a DLL to be installed in
>   more than one way, based on any criteria that is appropriate.
>
> To use DllInstall with regsvr32, add a "/i" flag followed by a colon
>   (:) and a string. The string will be passed to DllInstall as the
>   pszCmdLine parameter. If you omit the colon and string, pszCmdLine
>   will be set to NULL. The following example would be used to install a
>   DLL.
>
> ```
> regsvr32 /i:"Install_1" dllname.dll
> ```
>
> DllInstall is invoked with bInstall set to TRUE and pszCmdLine set to
>   "Install_1". To uninstall a DLL, use the following:
>
> ```
> regsvr32 /u /i:"Install_1" dllname.dll
> ```
>
> With both of the above examples, DllRegisterServer or
>   DllUnregisterServer will also be called. To call DllInstall only, add
>   a "/n" flag.
>
> ```
> regsvr32 /n /i:"Install_1" dllname.dll
> ```

Answer (score 1):

A VB6 COM DLL does not export `DLLInstall()` which is a function that serves as a way for a DLL to perform setup operations on itself (and is what `/i` tries to execute) so you do not need to worry about it.

Just use `regsvr32 dowFct.dll` (which calls `DllRegisterServer()` which the VB Compiler has added to the library for you.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run `regsvr32 /?`?

It shows me that there some attentional parameters are send to the DllInstall method of the dll file.

> /i:cmdline : Calls DllInstall passing it an optional [cmdline]. When used with /u, it calls dll uninstall.

[[source](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/regsvr32.mspx)]

Comment: I'm so far always assumed that dowFct.dll `regsvr32 /i dowFct.dll` is the same as `regsvr32 dowFct.dll`. Is not that so?

Comment: I'm not absolutly sure, but I guess that another method is called on the dll file but indeed without any input.