# How can I hide DLL registration message window in my application?

Tags: c#, .net, messagebox, regsvr32

I'm registering a dll at startup of my application by this command:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("regsvr32",strPath);
```

and after running this line of code , a window appears that says DLL registration was successful or not .

My question is that how can I hide this window in my application?

Comment: Type regsvr32.exe /? to see command line options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Process proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = "regsvr32",
        Arguments = "/s" + strPath,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};
proc.Start();
```

Also you can do this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("regsvr32","/s" + strPath);
```

Comment: thanx, but where should I add the locationPath of DLL?

Comment: @Shima.Y in `strPath`. (e.g) `strPath = Application.StartupPath + "//myDll.dll";`

Comment: if I define process as you said, in start method I cant pass strPath , I can just call Start() with no argument !

Comment: @Shima.Y What do you mean? You have to define `strPath` before you call process

Answer (score 3):

Use `/s – Silent; display no message boxes (added with Windows XP and Windows Vista)` option.

Source: [What is the different between /n and /i parameters of RegSvr32.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990216/what-is-the-different-between-n-and-i-parameters-of-regsvr32-exe)

Comment: would you help me with code ? where should I add /s in my above code ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268022/process-start-arguments or simply Process.Start("regsvr32", "/s /i path/to/lib.dll")